# Reading from specific row from a csv file and extract info by removing delimiter

Tags: c#, csv

I have this `csv file` and I want to start reading from line 9.

```py
1.756.369;0.025;0
1.723.979;0.025;0.0005
1.781.361;0.025;0.001
```

The above lines are the example of information in every row of the csv file. I would only like to extract the numbers before the second `.`, for example:

```py
1.756
1.723
1.781
```

How do I do that and also at the same time read the information separated by the `;` delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CsvReader
{
    public class CsvRecord
    {
        public string Col1 { get; set; }
        public string Col2 { get; set; }
        public string Col3 { get; set; }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");

            // Define how many lines you want to skip in Scip method parameter (8 - start with line 9)
            var csvRecords = csvLines.Skip(8)
                .Select(x => {
                    var items = x.Split(';');

                    var lastDotIndex = items[0].LastIndexOf('.');
                    return new CsvRecord
                    {
                        Col1 = lastDotIndex != -1 ? items[0].Remove(lastDotIndex) : items[0],
                        Col2 = items[1],
                        Col3 = items[2],
                    };
                })
                .ToList();

            // Just to output result    
            csvRecords.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Col1} - {x.Col2} - {x.Col3}"));
        }
    }
}
```

Add some checks to avoid exceptions in the part of code where new `CsvRecord` is created.

Or if you need only first column, then:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

var csvLines = File.ReadAllLines("test.csv");

// Define how many lines you want to skip in Scip method parameter (8 - start with line 9)
var csvRecords = csvLines.Skip(8)
    .Select(x => {
        var items = x.Split(';');

        var lastDotIndex = items[0].LastIndexOf('.');

        return lastDotIndex != -1 ? items[0].Remove(lastDotIndex) : items[0];
    })
    .ToList();

// Just to output result    
csvRecords.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Quite a lot of cluttered code for such a simple task. You should definitely use a simpler regex instead of splitting the strings again and again.

Comment: Please compare our two snippets for readability. The regex makes more sense in this case

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Okay, I think here everyone must decide personally what he prefers. But imagine the csv suddenly has 100 entries. What would you do then? You would have to create 100 properties in your class (CsvRecord), leaving aside the fact that it is bad to count up properties with a number (Col1, Col2, ....), because it is very difficult to reach them.

Comment: If he need all csv data, it doesn't matter how many colums would be added, he will HAVE to change his model, or add only needed properties. Your code just gets first col so it looks shorter, but it is easier to work with class collection of course.

Comment: I'm giving this to @IvanKhorin as this solves my problem and it's easy to understand as well cause I'm quite new to C# as well, thank you! But doome161 you're also right that if I have a lot of column/entries then I would have to come up with a lot of variables(Col1 Col2... Col100). I wonder if there's any way to optimize this. But huge thanks to both of you!

Comment: @IvanKhorin Sorry for interrupting again, I have 1900++ row but the rows are read until 1778 only. Is there any limits of reading the lines?

Comment: @JohnKhor, I've tested on 10k rows now, everything works fine, I've got exceptions when there are empty rows in the csv file, or there are less then 3 cols in some rows, but it is your task to perform some additional test as a programmer. Give me your csv file, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a regular expression and a for loop that starts on line 9:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d+([\.,]\d{3})");

string path = @"path/to/yourFile.csv";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    return;
}

string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

for (int i = 8; i < allLines.Length; i++) // starts on line 9
{
    var match = regex.Match(allLines[i]);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But the regex is an awesome idea to do so!